# Getting status updates from a coroutine

Tags: kotlin, callback, kotlinx.coroutines

Consider an asynchronous API that reports progress on its operations:

```
suspend fun operationWithIO(input: String, progressUpdate: (String) -> Unit): String {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement calls to `progressUpdate` such that callbacks are handled on the *caller's* dispatcher? Or is there a better way to deliver status updates back to the caller?

Answer (score 2):

You should send progress updates on a channel. That will allow the caller to listen to the channel using whatever dispatcher it wants.

```
suspend fun operationWithIO(input: String, progressChannel: Channel<String>): String {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // ...

        progressChannel.send("Done!")
        progressChannel.close()
    }
}
```

The caller can use it by doing something like this:

```
val progressChannel = Channel<String>()

someScope.launch {
    operationWithIO(input, progressChannel)
}

// Remember the call to progressChannel.close(), so that this iteration stops.
for (progressUpdate in progressChannel) {
    println(progressUpdate)
}
```

Comment: This works ... but it sure seems like a lot of boilerplate for the caller, with actual code happening out-of-order. Also if `operationWithIO` threw, the channel might never close and the caller's loop would never exit.

Comment: @gladed So you want the caller to react synchronously to the progress update?  What do you mean "out of order"?

Comment: @gladed And yes, you might need to handle exceptions. I left that out to not clutter the example with too much stuff unrelated to the question.

Comment: By out of order, I mean operationWithIO returns a result, and then later in the same routine, we process updates prior to the result arriving. I understand why, but it looks backwards.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the callback function and calling the wrapped function:

```
/** Return a new callback that invokes this callback on the current context. */
suspend fun <T> ((T) -> Unit).onCurrentContext(): (T) -> Unit =
    coroutineContext.let { context ->
        { value: T ->
            runBlocking {
                launch(context) {
                    this@onCurrentContext.invoke(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }

/** Perform a background operation, delivering status updates on the caller's context. */
suspend fun operationWithIO(statusUpdate: (String) -> Unit): String {
    val cb = statusUpdate.onCurrentContext()
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        cb("Phase 1")
        delay(150)
        cb("Phase 2")
        delay(150)
        "Result"
    }
}

// In use
runBlocking {
    val result = operationWithIO {
        println("received callback status $it")
    }
    println("result is $result")
}
```